# Mongo -Select parent document with maximum child documents count, Faster way?

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization

I'm quite new to mongo, and trying to get work following query.and is working fine too, But it's taking a little bit more time. I think I'm doing something wrong.

There are many number of documents in a collection `parent`, near about 6000. Each document has certain number of `childs` (childs is an another collection with 40000 documents in it). `parents & childs` are associated with each other by an attribute in the document called `parent_id`. Please see the following code. Following code takes approximate 1 minute to execute the queries. I don't think mongo should take that much time.

```
function getChildMaxDocCount(){
    var maxLen = 0;
    var bigSizeParent =  null;
    db.parents.find().forEach(function (parent){
    var currentcount = db.childs.count({parent_id:parent._id});
    if(currcount > maxLen){
        maxLen = currcount;
        bigSizeParent = parent._id;
    }
    });

    printjson({"maxLen":maxLen, "bigSizeParent":bigSizeParent });
}
```

Is there any feasible/optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you kidding? You do 6k queries in 40k documents and even some processing in a minute? Let's do some math: 60s/6000 = 0.01s or 10ms _per query_. And you call that _slow_? I call that freaking impressive assuming that you most likely don't even have a proper index set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to have the parent with the most childs. This is easy to accomplish using the aggregation framework. When each child only can have one parent, the aggregation query would look like this

```
db.childs.aggregate(
  { $group: { _id:"$parent_id", children:{$sum:1} } },
  { $sort: { "children":-1 } },
  { $limit : 1 }
);
```

Which should return a document like:

```
 { _id:"SomeParentId", children:15}
```

If a child can have more than one parent, it heavily depends on the data modeling how the query would look like.

Have a look at the [aggregation framework documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) for details.

#### Edit: Some explanation

The aggregation pipeline takes every document it is told do do so through a series of steps in a way that all documents are first processed through the first step and the resulting documents are put into the next step.

Step 1: Grouping

We group all documents into new documents (virtual ones, if you want) and tell mongod to increment the field `children` by one for each document which has the same `parent_id`. Since we are referring to a field of the current document, we need to add a `$` sign.

Step 2: Sorting

Now that we have a bunch of documents which hold the parent_id and the number of children this parent has, we sort it by the `children` field in descending (`-1`) order.

Step3: Limiting

Since we are only interested in the `parent_id` which has the most children, we only let mongod return the first document after sorting.

Comment: :- Thank you very much!, I was looking for something like this. It was new thing for me to learn about aggregation in mongo.